# 1e+0.8= What? What does E mean?

Tags: linear-regression, extrapolation, slope

Hello I came across a math equation and I was wondering what did the "e" stand for? 
the equation is : y=47931x-1E+0.8
Can someone please help me by showing what the E stands for and the answer for my equation. 
I know that I need to sub in a point for x so the only thing stopping me from answering the question is what to do for the 1E+0.8 part.

Comment: It is scientific notation, the e or E stands for $10^x$ where x is the number following the e/E

Comment: Are you sure it is $E+0.8$? That decimal point seems unlikely.

Comment: Can you write down *exactly* what the expression said.  Is "x" the letter $x$ or the times symbol $\times$.  I s the E capitolized or not.  And what *was* the equation?  Was this a math book?  A chemistry book?  What was the equation supposed to *mean*?  And were any of the terms "rised" ?  $1E$ vs $1^E$ or ... whatever.

Comment: Why was this question upvoted? The tags are all wrong! We do not know whether $x$ in the equation is a variable or just the times symbol. The question is not clear!

Answer (score 1):

If it's a capital *E*, it should be *scientific notation*, specifically *[E notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation)*.

Because 100,000,000 takes up a lot of space and can be difficult to compare with other numbers, it's written as $1$x$10^8$. Some calculators (and some books, to match) write this with an E:

[image: Avogadro's constant in E notation]
[By PRHaney - Own work, CC BY-SA 3.0](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=9472958)

But that's done with integers, and you have $0.8$, so it must be

$$y = 47931x - e^{0.8},$$

using the natural exponential function.

Note that you **can** use lowercase *e* for scientific notation, but capital *E* should not be used for the natural exponential function.

Comment: Note that it's not unheard of to use a lower-case `e` for scientific notation. For instance, in many programming languages, when formatting output of numbers, the are presets for both conventions.

Comment: [+1] Nice piece of art. We could call it E-art...

Comment: @Arthur Thanks! I added that in.

Answer (score 0):

E = Exponentiation in base $10$.

Examples:

$$1.23\ \text{E+0.2} = 1.23\cdot 10^{0.2}$$

$$1.23\ \text{E-2.1} = 1.23\cdot 10^{-2.1}$$

Comment: But you you must admit the use of a decimal, while not theoretically impossible is highly unusual.  The usual *point* of scientific notation is to shift decimal points so it is usually always done iwht positive or negative integers.

Comment: Yes, indeed is quite strange. I just gave a generalisation of the meaning, but I wouldn't ever expect a non integer exponential!

Comment: This is probably the correct interpretation (I'm having a hard time thinking of any other) but I think we need to clarify where the OP read the expression and was it actually written as such.  Hypothetically $y = 47931x - 1E+0.8$ *could* mean $y = 47931x - 10^{0.8} = 47931x - \sqrt[5]{10,000}$ but that would be .... weird.